# Handling blank columns in PHP table generation from an array

Tags: php

I'm creating a three column table of form fields with the code below. Each row has three columns. If the total number of fields is not a multiple of three then the last row doesn't contain blank form fields in the remaining columns.

How can I amend this to complete the remaining columns with blank form fields?

```
<?php
$listCount = count($col);

for ($i = 0; $i < $listCount; ++$i) {    
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<tr class="list_row">'; 
    } ?>

    <td><input type="text" style="width: 190px;" name="inputCol1[]" value="<?php echo $col[$i] ?>" /></td>
         
    <?php 
    if($i % 3 == 3) {
         echo '</tr>'; 
    }
}  
?>
```

Comment: As a side note, if you're only echoing one line or two of HTML with a lot of PHP, it makes sense to `echo` it and do a way with all the opening/closing PHP tags.

Comment: Also, $i % 3 should never == 3.

Comment: It looks almost ok for me at the first sight, just change `if($i % 3 == 3)` to `if($i % 3 == 2)`, as you will never have modulo result equal to 3 (only 0, 1, 2).

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Edited the question for clarity looking to finish the last row's columns with blank fields. Right now it just ends with the last field generate by $i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete the last row after the `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $listCount; ++$i) {  
  ...
}
if ( ($i % 3) < 2 ) {
  do {
    echo "<td>...</td>";
    $i++;
  } while ($i % 3 != 2);
}
```

Also, take a look at the comments below your question as `$i % 3` will never be `3`.

**Note:** I really should combine the `if` and `do` in one nice condition / loop, but it's too late for that, this should at least work...

Comment: Thx. Makes perfect sense. Just tried it out and it's created one more column, but the third is still blank. Also changed if($i % 3 == 2). Trying to figure out if I'm missing something?

Comment: @jsuissa I have made a small logical mistake. It should work now although it can probably be optimized.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the efforts -- still generating just one column. So I changed the last line to `} while ($i % 3);` and that seemed to do it.

Comment: I would change the if to `$i % 3 > 0` because you don't want to add an extra row when the number of items is divisible by 3.

Comment: @David Harkness That's where went wrong as well; the problem is that the count starts at 0 and when `$i % 3 == 0` a row and the first column is added. You could probably write a simpler loop if the count started at 1 and you can simply use `$i % 3 > 0`

Comment: @jeroen - Don't forget that `$i` will equal the last location that was *not* filled in. Ending with `$i % 3 = 0` means a complete row was added. Starting with one would be no easier.

Answer (score -1):

just change

```
 if($i % 3 == 3) {
     echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

to

```
if($i % 3 == 2) {   
     echo '</tr><br />'; 
}
```

It will work.

Comment: No, you need to emit extra empty `<td>` elements when the total number of elements is not divisible by three.

Comment: well , I'm sorry I mistook the meaning , I thought he just want to leave blank in the remaining field.